# How to refresh F-Curve colors via python?

Tags: scripting, interface

To refresh colors F-Curves I have to display the Graph editor on the screen.
Blender doesn't refresh colors F-Curves automatically.

Create some animation with the default cube and follow:

```
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction'].fcurves[0].color
```

without display the Graph editor on the screen, we get a pure black color:

```
Color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

It the any way to refresh and update colors F-Curves via python ?

*Below a screenshot from Outliner, Datablocks.*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the fcurves colors are calculated when the graph editor tries to read their value for the first time, so you may have to do that yourself :

```
for action in D.actions :    
    for fcurve in action.fcurves :
        index = fcurve.array_index

        if fcurve.color_mode == 'AUTO_RGB':
            h = float(1.0)/3.0        
        #I don't have the right formula for rainbow 
        elif fcurve.color_mode == 'AUTO_RAINBOW': 
            h = float(1.0)/4.0  

        fcurve.color.hsv = (index*h, 1, 1)
```

Comment: For me the colors were updated only after I changed the color_mode to 'CUSTOM' (fcurve.color_mode = 'CUSTOM')